# Assign user as farm administrator

Tags: farm-admin

I need to assign a new user as farm administrator on a development machine. I added him to the domain admins AD group, and went to farm admins in central administration and gave added him there. He opens visual studio on that machine and tries to deployed an app, but he can't due to lack of permissions.. he got this error:

> The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is
>   running and connected to the SharePoint farm

I figured that I need to give him access on sql as well, but is there a command in powershell that lets me add a farm admin and it does all of the work together? or do I need to do all these steps manually?

Comment: will it grant permissions on other services other than sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via using Powershell. Run the below command

`Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName CONTOSO\User1`

Read more about it here :https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596.aspx

Comment: will it grant permissions on other services other than sql?

Comment: It grant all the required permission as an farm admin. But if you want give him complete control I think u should add him into local admin group on server

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: I still have the issue of: Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://servername/sites/apps. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.

Comment: Can he access site in browser?

Comment: Is he site collection admin as well?

Comment: I think this error is different what u ask, I would start new question with that error so that more visibility....also check https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ddeeaa4-9409-4d8d-8618-c4da75c25876/invalide-url-while-creating-sharepoint-solution?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Here it is http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178529/cannot-connect-to-the-sharepoint-site-deploying-an-add-in