# Cannot connect to the SharePoint site, deploying an add-in

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013

I am having this error when I am trying to deploy a SharePoint Hosted Add-in to a local SharePoint Server, using visual studio 2013:

> Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: servername/sites/apps. Make
>   sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on
>   the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if
>   the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the
>   project, update the Site URL property of the project...

This is a new farm, I just configured apps on my machine. I tried deploying with system account, but visual studio didn't allow me to deploy with it, so we tried using different user's credentials for it, and assigned him as farm admin.

What else needs to be done?

Comment: can you try package the add-in and manually upload it, or use powershell to make the deployment.

Comment: how do I do that? I uploaded the .app file to the document library in sharepoint, is that right?

Comment: check out this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192008/deploy-apps-to-sharepoint-2013-on-premises